# How to calculate pair production cross section?

Tags: scattering-cross-section, pair-production

I've adapted the following equation [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production) to calculate the pair production cross section $\sigma_x$ for a photon decaying into a pair of particles $x^+ x^-$ :

$\sigma_x = \alpha \times(r_x)^2\times Z^2 \times P(E_\gamma, Z)$

$\alpha$ is the fine structure constant, 
$r_x$ is the radius of particle $x$, 
$Z$ is the atomic number of the material on which the photon is incident, 
$E_\gamma$ is the energy of the incident photon, 
$P(E_\gamma, Z)$ is '*some complex-valued function that depends on the energy and atomic number*'

What is this function $P(E_\gamma, Z)$, how does one calculate it?

Comment: What Wikipedia article did this come from

Comment: [Pair Production Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production). It is quoted as being a simplified version of a more complicated function derived using quantum electrodynamics.

Comment: Technically your answer is in the preceding few sentences, you need to calculate the Feynman diagrams to figure out what $P$ is as it depends on the material. They've just stated that if you do the usual QFT calculation of a Feynman diagrams, that you can then write the cross section in that following form.